# Can we call php scripts which are stored on firebase cloud storage?

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

I just want to ask that if we can store php api scripts on firebase cloud storage and call them like we do when the php api scripts are stored on our website's server to get the data on mobile app.
If possible then how. Please let me know.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35524033/7634960

Comment: Why do you want to use Cloud Storage for this?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer - no.

Cloud Storage is designed to store static assets, such as uploaded documents or images.

If you attempt to call a PHP script from the Cloud Storage the PHP file will be downloaded to the user - instead of executing the script.