# .php is getting downloaded instead of loading it on firebase web hosting

Tags: javascript, php, html, firebase, firebase-hosting

I have hosted a web app on Firebase. While redirecting from index.html file to details.php file, .php is getting downloaded instead of loading it on firebase web hosting. Details.php file contains php, html and Javascript code. I don't understand why it is getting downloaded instead of loading it. Please help me out.

Comment: I was under the impression that firebase is for static files

Comment: [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35523819/simple-php-contact-form-with-firebase-hosting

Comment: @Dale Is it really so? I didn't know this

Comment: @Jamie_D thank you. this means I can't use .php file :/