# Firebase Hosting - PHP Starts file download

Tags: php, html, firebase, web-deployment, web-hosting

I have just put up a site on firebase, on it is a form where users can put in their database credentials to access it remotely. The form uses `POST` to send the details to a php page, and its code looks like this:

```html
<form name="login-form" action="login.php" method="post">
  <input autocomplete="off" name="ip_address" type="text" placeholder="Enter DB IP"/>
  <br/>
  <input autocomplete="off" name="db" type="text" placeholder="Enter DB Name"/>
  <br/>
  <input autocomplete="off" name="username" type="text" placeholder="Enter Username"/>
  <br/> 
  <input name="password" type="password" placeholder="Enter Password"/>
  <br/>
  <input id="login-button" type="submit" value=">"/>
</form>
```

Using my apache2 web server, this process works fine, and the user is redirected, however when deployed with firebase (`firebase deploy --only hosting`), the process instead triggers a file download of `login.php`. Why is this happening? The file structure for the public folder is exactly the same as it is for apache, as is each files content.

Comment: This happens when Apache2 has no configured php handler. Make sure php-fpm for example is installed.

Comment: I see, as I say apache2 actually works fine, it is firebase that is causing the issue. I did install php-fpm but it had no effect, presumably because the files aren't being stored on my server.

Comment: I don't think that apache2 is ok. Then it would execute the PHP file and deliver its output. `firebase deploy --only hosting` may change the configuration.

Comment: Firebase Hosting doesn't support PHP https://stackoverflow.com/a/35524033/284325

Comment: Ah, thank you. Well since I'm not willing to rewrite this entire site with nodejs I'll try and find a different hosting platform.